# Finding a PDF from a function

Tags: probability, functions

I have a function $y = f(x),\ x\in\mathbb{R}$ (assume $f(x)= \sin(x)/x$ if you need an example). How can I find the probability distribution function (PDF) of $y$, assuming $x\sim U(\mathbb{R})$ (uniformly distributed over the reals)? I'm a little rusty on whether the end points are problematic in defining it over the reals, so if that's an issue, let's make it simpler and say that $x\in\mathcal{D}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $x\sim U(\mathcal{D})$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is an interval.

Do I explicitly need to know the inverse $x = f^{-1}(y)$ in order to be able to compute it?

Comment: Do you mean, we have given a random variable $X$ and you want the PDF of $f(X)$?

Comment: You have a relation between $x$ and $y$. In order to understand the distribution of $y$, you should know the distribution of $x$. Since there is no obvious or "canonical" probability measure on $\mathbb R$, it is not clear how $x$ is distributed. ¶ Welcome to MSE, by the way.

Comment: @75064 $x$ is uniformly distributed on the reals. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: @lmn There is no such thing as "uniformly distributed over the reals".

Comment: @75064 Not even on a closed interval $\mathcal{D}$ as I have in my edit to the question? As I said, I'm a bit rusty on whether or not I can define it as I said in my comment above, but what I mean is that any value of $x\in\mathcal{D}$ has an equal probability of occurring

Comment: @75064 Thanks, added that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is uniformly distributed over interval, its distribution can be written as $c\,|dx|$ where $c$ is  constant ($c=1/\ell$ where $\ell$ is the length of the interval). This suggests the  formula for distribution of $y$, namely $c\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|\,|dy|$. However, for  $\frac{dx}{dy}$ to make sense, we need the inverse function $x(y)$. If the given function $y(x)$ is not one-to-one, then its domain should be divided into subintervals on which it is one-to-one (that is, either increasing or decreasing).

Example: $x$ is uniformly distributed over $[-\pi/2,\pi]$, $y=\sin x$. The density of $x$ is $c=1/(3\pi/2)=2/(3\pi)$.

- On the interval  $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ the values of $y$ run from $-1$ to $1$. The inverse function is $\sin^{-1}y$, with derivative $1/\sqrt{1-y^2}$. Therefore, this interval contributes $c\,(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\chi_{[-1,1]}$ to the pdf of $y$.
- On the interval  $[\pi/2,\pi ]$ the values of $y$ run from $ 1$ to $ 0$. The inverse function is $\pi-\sin^{-1}y$, with derivative $-1/\sqrt{1-y^2}$. Therefore, this interval contributes $c\,(1-y^2)^{-1/2}\chi_{[0,1]}$ to the pdf of $y$.

Adding the above, we get the final answer: the pdf of $y$ is 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3\pi} (1-y^2)^{-1/2} \quad & -1\le y\le 0 \\ \\
\frac{4}{3\pi} (1-y^2)^{-1/2} \quad & 0\le y\le 1 \\ \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The example $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is much less tractable, because there's no nice formula for the inverse.